# edit not working correctly on my ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I created an app to Create, Edit and delete BOMs in a database.

When I attempt to make a change to the Item number it makes the item number field null in the database and if I change the QTY for the item it also make the item number field null but it will commit the QTY change.

Your help would be appreciated.
  My code is below:

This is my Controller code for the edit:

```
// GET: RovingHeaders/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var rovingHeader = await _context.RovingHeader
                .Include(s => s.RovingLine)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RovingNo == id);


            if (rovingHeader == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(rovingHeader);
        }

        // POST: RovingHeaders/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("RovingNo,Description,ModDate")] RovingHeader rovingHeader, [Bind("RovingNo,ItemNo,Qty,RowId")] RovingLine rovingLine)
        {
            if (id != rovingHeader.RovingNo)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(rovingHeader);
                    _context.Update(rovingLine);



                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!RovingHeaderExists(rovingHeader.RovingNo))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(rovingHeader);
        }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!
My JSON file

```
Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SPECContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SPECContext-0afacde4-1953-4537-8410-5d670f37debc;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MONTEREYContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MONTEREYContext-0afacde4-1953-4537-8410-5d670f37debc;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }

}
```

My UI file Edit.CSHTML

```
@model Spec5.Models.RovingHeader
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
<h1>Edit</h1>
<h4></h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="RovingNo" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ModDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ModDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ModDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>QTY</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>                            
                                @foreach (var item in Model.RovingLine)
                                {
                                 <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <input type="hidden" name="Roving Number" value="@item.RovingNo" />
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="Part Number" value="@item.ItemNo" />
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="Qty" value="@item.Qty" />
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="RowId" value="@item.RowId" />
                                 </td>
                                 </tr>
                                }                            
                       </tr>
                    </table>           
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />                    
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint just inside your Edit action, does `rovingLine.ItemNo` have a value?

Comment: No, the field is null.

Comment: Why is it pulling in the QTY value but not the ItemNo value?

Comment: What does the incoming JSON look like?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you place your UI code as well atleast for the fields you are referring to.

Comment: I have added the UI and JSON to my original question

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It was the Name that was the issue.

```
<td>
                                    <input type="text" name="Part Number" value="@item.ItemNo" />
                                 </td>
```

The name need to be the same as the Model.  I change the name from name="Part Number' to name="ItemNo" and everything worked.

Thank you